# Raspberry Pi serial communication issue

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to setup serial communication between Raspberry Pi and PC by referring the tutorial below:
https://scribles.net/setting-up-serial-communication-between-raspberry-pi-and-pc/

the communication is within Termites (PC) and Minicom (Raspberry Pi).

After I done all the setting, the communications seems working. However, the character that sent between 2 devices is weird.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to set up both ends of the serial link to the same settings.

Comment: Baudrate should be the same too...

Comment: Hi, i had double checked the baudrate and the setting are same on both side.